# Javascript Dynamically build HTML table with button cell

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to get my dynamic table to have a button in last column.  Have had no luck.  Any help much appreciated.

```
var removeRow=document.createElement("BUTTON");

                //Add the data rows.
                for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        if (j==0) {
                        cell.innerHTML = data[i].userId}
                        if (j==1) {
                        cell.innerHTML = data[i].id}
                        if (j==2) {
                        cell.innerHTML = data[i].title}
                        if (j==3) {
                        cell.appendChild(removeRow)// Not working when replace data[i].field with button variable.
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is cell? Without the html it's hard to tell, but possibly try: `cell.parentElement.appendChild(removeRow)`

Comment: That is strange, do it in one line, do a statment. `cell.innerHTML="<td>"+data[i].userId ....+"<\td>".`

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, j never gets to 3 (it says `j < 3` in your second *for* statement).
If you change that to `j < 4` or `j <= 3` it should work.

Apart from that, you are only creating one BUTTON element, which you will be appending to all rows. Every time you append it to a row, it will be removed from the previous row it was on, so you'll still be left with just one button.

Comment: I have corrected 3 to 4.

Cell is derived for the row below

    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
     var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
     headerCell.innerHTML = 'Header1';
     row.appendChild(headerCell);
    }